# activity in fragment menu

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, android-menu

I'm a noob in app building but i'm trying!
I've build the base of an app, first try in android studio.
Build a menu with fragments in it.
However i would like to have one menu-item linked to an activity (because I would like it to look different than the rest.)
Tried a lot but it doesn't work.
could u help me?

this is my menu code:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {

        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        Zakkaartjes fragment = new Zakkaartjes();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
        Rekenen fragment = new Rekenen();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
         //THIS IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO HAVE A LINK TO MY "notities activity"

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
        Protocollen fragment = new Protocollen();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                "mailto","info@verpleegkundigzakboek.nl", null));
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Email van verpleegkundig zakboek app");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Verzend e-mail"));

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
    }
```

Made Notities.java (with the other layout in it) and made activity_notities.xml
Hope anyone can help me?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should work :

```
else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourNextActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Also, you could consider use a `switch` instead of lots of `else if` :

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getId()){
        case R.id.nav_camera:
            //your code
            break;
        case R.id.nav_gallery:
            //your code
            break;
        // add case blocks for each id you want to manage
    }
}
```

More on `switch` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).